# Method toString is undefined JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with key-value pair of `JS` objects.

```
<div id="parent" class="parent">
    <div id="child" class="child">
        <input type="text" class="text"/>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()"/>
    </div>
<div>
```

and corresponding `JS` code:

```
function doThis(){
    var span= document.createElement("span");
    var parent=document.getElementById("parent");
    var child=document.getElementById("child");
    var submit=document.getElementById("submit");
    child.insertBefore(span,submit);
    myKeys=[];
    for(var key in submit){
        myKeys.push("{"+key);
        myKeys.push(" "+submit.key + "}");
    }  
    span.innerHTML=myKeys;
}
```

It works correctly. But if we replace `submit.key` to `submit.key.toString()` it doesn't work.   **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bundos/BYwz9/3/)**. I dont understand why the error's description is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined.` `toString` method defined for all `JS` object.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? key value pair of what from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because of:

```
submit.key
```

you need to use:

```
submit[key]
```

Not only that, but calling `toString()` on this will fail if the key is *null* or *undefined*. So, better try-catch it and then review the log.

See your updated fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/BYwz9/4/**

Hope that helps.

*Update*: (*regarding the syntax of object key bracket notation*)

From this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or
>   anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty
>   string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript
>   identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen,
>   or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square
>   bracket notation. This notation is also very useful when property
>   names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not
>   determined until runtime).

In order to check the difference it makes in your use-case, please change the fiddle to both notations and check the console log.

Comment: Please, explain what's a difference between `submit.key` and `submit[key]`?

Comment: @St.Antario: there. updated the answer. not much difference, but there are scenarios when bracket notation is safe.

Answer (score 1):

submit.key will be undefined since you meant submit[key]. Object accessors are required since you want to use the variable to lookup the property.

Answer (score 1):

On checking what **`submit`** holds, I got

```
console.log(submit)
```

returns

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="doThis()"/>
```

Whereas,

```
console.log(submit.key) //returns undefined
```

because `submit` does not hold `key`

Hence the error, `toString() method cannot call of undefined`